# Foursquare Not Reading hCard Data?

Tags: foursquare

I've got all the hCard data in my site, but it's not able to parse it... formatting is right, an exact copy/paste from the example given, but it's not reading...

http://southwestrestaurants.com/restaurant/flying-star-cafe-3/

Any Ideas?

Comment: Please flesh this out with some examples of the hCard data as well as how you are setting it up, etc, etc and we can move this to Webapps.  In it's current state, this is very NARQ/Too Localized.

Answer (score 0):

Your hCard is correct and the JS is, in fact, parsing it. The foursquare debug tool doesn't show hCard data because your server is returning mobile optimized version of the page, which doesn't contain the same microformat mark-up that your desktop version returns.

As far as we know, the foursquare debug tool is making a "naked" request (no special headers / user-agent), do you know why your server would be returning the mobile version of the site in this case?